# Why am I unable to edit this question?

Tags: support, editing

I am on smartphone at this time and I think about editing this question: [How Can I Pass Bootloader (Huawei Y200 stuck logo/ Boot-Loop)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34183/how-can-i-pass-bootloader-huawei-y200-stuck-logo)

Unfortunately, I am unable to see any `edit` link. Why?

- I have 7k+ reputation which gives me edit privilege.
- I can see edit link on other questions.

What's going on?

Answer (score 8):

Probably because there's an edit pending.

Comment: This was it. I remember seeing an edit pending for it earlier, @eldarerathis took care of it